# Python: How to split input from database into a 2d array

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, uwamp

I'm using a mySQL database on uwamps to store data on names and highscores of people who've played a game, and I need to get that data into a 2D array. So far, I've managed to get the data in as a 1D array, which looks like this when i print it:

```
[('name1', 4), ('name2', 3), ('name3', 2), ('name4', 6), ('name5', 1)]
```

I need what's inside each set of normal brackets to be a seperate list, like this:

```
    [['name1', 4], ['name2', 3], ['name3', 2], ['name4', 6], ['name5', 1]]
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: The `''` mean its a string. You cannot remove that, its part of the python syntax not the text itself. And please provide an example of what your output should look like

Comment: the apostrophes indicate that the name is a string, you probably want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just convert the touples to a list:

```
userscores=[('name1', 4), ('name2', 3), ('name3', 2), ('name4', 6), ('name5', 1)]

userscores=[list(user) for user in userscores]
```